# Do questions about coding for Web plugins go on stackoverflow or superuser?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to post a question about writing a web page which uses the QuickTime plugin. I've seen some of these questions on SE:
[Handle missing QuickTime plugin with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613558/handle-missing-quicktime-plugin-with-firefox)

And I've seen another moved to SU:
[Quicktime plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344079/quicktime-plugin)

Where do these questions belong? Is there something fundamentally different about them that determines why one is in SE and the other in SU? I'd like to post my similar question in the correct place.

I have written an HTML embed statement for QuickTime. In my case, Firefox directs me to download the missing QuickTime plugin (and everything works as expected). However IE 8 just displays a broken image icon.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail about what you would like to ask? Then we would be more able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Jim, I added a description of what my question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are vastly different questions.  One is about what the appropriate tags/code are so that a user's QuickTime plugin will work appropriately.  The latter is asking why their one doesn't work for a specific tag, not one that they are trying to modify.  So, to answer your question, as long as they are about **coding** they belong on Stack Overflow.

Also, as a note, that second question hasn't been migrated to SuperUser, though it should likely be closed on SO or migrated.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know where to post. It's Stack Overflow in my case since I'm writing a web page.